# PHP simpletest tomfoolery. Test doesn't pass on working method

Tags: php, simpletest

I've been writing a test for a simple Datamapper class, and I know the method is working, however the test fails and gives me the error "`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Call log\tests\model_tests.php on line 13.`" Obviously, this can't be right, because I can verify that the method works.

Here is the code that it's supposedly erroring on:

```
function all() {
    $calls = $this->pdo->query('SELECT * from calls');
    return $calls->fetchAll();
}
```

Here's my test code:

```
class TestOfCallMapper extends UnitTestCase {
    function testOfReturnsAll() {
        $this->createSchema();
        $mapper = Callmapper::getInstance();
        $results = $mapper->all();
        print_r($results);
    }

    private function createSchema() {
        $mapper = CallMapper::getInstance();
        $mapper->pdo->exec(file_get_contents('../database/create_schema.sql'));
    }

    private function destroySchema() {
        $mapper = CallMapper::getInstance();
        $mapper->pdo->exec(file_get_contents('../database/destroy_schema.sql'));
    }
}

$test = new TestOfCallMapper('Test of CallMapper Methods');
$test->run(new HTMLReporter());
```

If I do this, it works just fine:

```
    $mapper = CallMapper::getInstance();
    $test = $mapper->all();
    print_r($test->fetchAll());
```

Comment: please var_dump() or print_r() $test to see if it realy is an object.

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose if you put what the result of a var_dump of `$results` was (var_dump will output something in the case of `bool(FALSE)`)

Comment: It doesn't output anything on the test page if I attempt to print_r or var_dump $results. On the other page, it outputs an array containing all of the database entries for $test.

Comment: Ok, that makes me sound really dumb because obviously an array isn't an object. I changed the method. I will update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdo query is evidently failing, thus you are trying to call fetchAll on false.

I'd check why it's failing.

Comment: I realized this, but it returns correctly on another page. The only thing that I can think is happening is that somehow Simpletest is making the PDO query fail. I don't see why or how this could possibly happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your PDO Query is returning false therefore its not and instance of PDO but a boolean, Try something like this!

```
function all() {
    $calls = $this->pdo->query('SELECT * from calls');
    if($calls === false)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to perform query");
    }
    return $calls->fetchAll();
}
```

and then within your `TestOfCallMapper` you can do:

```
function testOfReturnsAll()
{
        $this->createSchema();

        $mapper = Callmapper::getInstance();
        try
        {
            $results = $mapper->all();
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            //Some Logging for $e->getMessage();
            return;
        }
        //Use $results here        
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and did something similar to that earlier. it returns this message:

Comment: Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Comment: I tried setting the attribute it lists in the PDO constructor. It didn't help.